# how to increase the tabpanel height and width which is created in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs3, extjs-mvc

I have a  TabPanel, where the TabPanel contains two parts, one part has details about the image and the down part has the image which is created using Panel. Now the image is unreadable in IE8(less size), so i want to increase the size of the Imagepanel in the Tabpanel. How can i achieve this?

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    activeTab : 0,
    autoScroll: true,
    width:200,
    height: 200,
        items:[]      
    });
```